# Java: How to loop through an array and check that it matches a variable value?

Tags: java, loops, scope, boolean, arguments

I have an argument which is of type char. I want to check that this char is lower case, if this is true then I will make a boolean variable equal true, otherwise, make it equal false. I have created an array of chars:

```
String argumentStr = args[2];
char argument = argumentStr.charAt(0);
boolean acceptArgument;

char[] lowerCaseAlphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                            'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
```

Then I have tried two different solutions, but each is outside of the scope of my acceptArgument boolean.

First:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
        if (argument == lowerCaseAlphabet[i]) {
            acceptArgument = true;
        } else {
            acceptArgument = false;
        }
    }
```

Second:

```
for (char letter: lowerCaseAlphabet) {
        if (argument == letter) {
            acceptArgument = true;
        } else {
            acceptArgument = false;
        }
    }
```

I understand why it won't work, because of the scope of the if statements compared with the acceptArgument boolean. But I don't know how to get around this. Please advise.

Comment: add `break;` after `acceptArgument = true;`

Comment: No, that's not a scope problem. Use your debugger, or add println() statements inside the if and inside the else, and you should understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand why it won't work, because of the scope of the if statements compared with the acceptArgument boolean

No. the reason is not scope, it is because of at each iteration `acceptArgument` is getting either `false` or `true`based on if condition until it finishs the whole loop because you did not use any `break` or what ever to get out of the loop when match found.

For example if `argument = 'p'`, it will find match at `letter='p'`, and therefore `acceptArgument` will be set to `true`. However, the loop advances to next letter `q`, since`p != q`, `acceptArgument` will be set to `false` and continues like that. that is why it is not working what you expect.

see the correction below

to correct your code, make the following modification

First initialize;

```
boolean acceptArgument=false;
```

Second remove `else` it should be like this

```
for (char letter: lowerCaseAlphabet) {
    if (argument == letter) 
        acceptArgument = true;          
}
```

it works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an extra array for this. You can check if `argument` is lower case by comparing the result to `Character.toLowerCase(char)` like

```
char argument = argumentStr.charAt(0);
boolean acceptArgument = argument == Character.toLowerCase(argument);
```

**or** (as pointed out by @JBNizet) use `Character.isLowerCase(char)` like

```
boolean acceptArgument = Character.isLowerCase(argument);
```

If you also need to test that the character is a letter you can add an and for that like

```
boolean acceptArgument = Character.isLetter(argument) 
        && Character.isLowerCase(argument);
```

Comment: Why not just call isLowerCase()?

Comment: @JBNizet Or that indeed. :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is not equivalent, "э" is lower case but not in `a-z`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I should also mention that I need the argument to only be letters, it can't be numbers or special characters. What would I do in this instance?